# How to send data to iPhone from external device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I have an external device that we manufacture that basically monitors 4 voltages, converts them to a 16 bit digital number then streams this info back to a PC every 100mS or so, using a serial over USB style chip. Basically a data logging system.

We would now like to collect this information on an iPhone and I am wondering what is the best way to get the data into the iPhone?

I am assuming there is no way we can physically connect directly to the iPhone dock connector as the protocol to do this is not available to iOS developers?

Obviously we could do it over a WiFi network but there will not always be one and we want to keep the external hardware fairly simple, i.e. no need for a computer or Wireless router etc.

If we add Bluetooth connectivity to our hardware would this work? I read that only 'Made for iPod' type Bluetooth devices will connect, in which case how can we achieve 'made for iPod' status? It would be relatively easy to add the necessary Bluetooth chips to get the system up and running.

In an ideal world we would like to do this without having to use a 3rd party interface.

I have been thinking about trying to digitise data as an audio signal – like  a modem, and send it into the line input jack, but I don’t think it will be fast enough – this would be new territory for me.

Anyway all suggestions gratefully received!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about hardware development but, have you looked at this: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ ?

Comment: You can use CoreBluetooth APIs to interface over Bluetooth 4.0 (Low Energy) without using MFi

Comment: I would like to avoid MFi if possible. A couple of thoughts occur to me: 1) If I use a HID type BT interface module apparently this does not need to be MFi. I could send information as ASCII using key strokes - yes the RX Handler would be a pain, but it's do able. How would Apple feel about this when I submit the app? Its a lot of work to go through only to have it rejected because I'm using a HID device in a 'different' way and there would be no quick alternative. 2) Is it possible to buy a MFi pre approved BT module that can be utilised within our hardware? Are there any other options?

Comment: The solution needs to be backwards compatible with iPhone 3GS ideally 3G.